# Compilation error when trying to compile body of a method used in SFINAE checks

Tags: c++, sfinae

I have this well-known example of a class that detects if a type is a class, or not.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>                                        
class ClassDetector {
private:
    typedef char One;
    typedef struct { char a[2]; } Two;

    template <typename C> static One test(int C::*) {
        compilation error;
    }

    template <typename C> static Two test(...);

public:
    enum { Yes = sizeof(ClassDetector<T>::test<T>(0)) == 1 };
    enum { No = !Yes };
};

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", ClassDetector<int>::Yes);
    return 0;
}
```

The code doesn't compile on `GCC` and `Clang`, because "compilation error" isn't defined anywhere and the compiler doesn't know what it is. But it works under `Visual Studio`. This suggests that Visual Studio completely skips the body of the first `test` method, and doesn't even check anything inside.

So, the question is: who is right in this case? GCC/Clang or VS? Should the method be checked for compilation errors or this isn't necessary and isn't enforced by the standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are building using permissive mode in VS which disables two-phase lookup (which has been recently implemented). [Disabling permissive mode by specifying `/permissive-` argument will cause compilation in VS to fail as well](https://godbolt.org/z/6g01o7).

Comment: Thanks for the 'two-phase lookup' hint, with this I was able to find an interesting article about it: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/